# Regression coefficient DiD

Tags: regression

Following the discussion on: https://www.publichealth.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods/difference-difference-estimation
If we specify the regression equation to estimate the DiD as:
$$Y= β_0 + β_1*[Time]  + β_3*[Time*Intervention] + β_4*[Covariates]+ε$$

instead of :

$$Y= β_0 + β_1*[Time] + β_2*[Intervention] + β_3*[Time*Intervention] + β_4*[Covariates]+ε$$

Our $β_3$ coefficient would still be yielding the DiD estimator right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The estimator from the first equation would be biased. One of the assumptions of difference-in-difference estimations is that potential variations between the treatment and control group are accounted for and constant over time (parallel trends assumption). That's the "constant difference in outcome" in Figure 1 from your link. If you don't control for `Intervention`, then that constant difference assumption is no longer part of your parametric equation.

Similarly, you must control for `Time` because of the parallel trends assumption - both groups are expected to have evolved in the same way over time in the counterfactual that neither received a treatment.

Without either assumption, you no longer have a quasi-experimental design and an argument for the DiD estimator being an estimate of the causal effect of the treatment.